# How to add search box inside <select> tag with ng-option

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options, search-box

I need to add search box inside the select tag with ng-option.

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="modelname" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in Categories ng-change="getSubCategory()">
<option><--search box should be here--></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use Bootstrap-select Live-search :http://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with standard html. You'll have to create something custom - something along these lines.

```
<ul class="custom-select">
    <li class="custom-select__option" ng-repeat="o in $ctrl.options"><input type="search"/></li>
<ul>
```

It won't be hard to create, but that's the direction you'll need to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could set your `search` value when user hits the button.
live sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/jTRmBH.

template:

```
 <label>
 Search Value: <input ng-model="filter">*emphasized text*
 </label><br>
 <label>
 Search Key:
 <select ng-model="key">
   <option value="$">Any</option>
   <option value="number">Student Number</option>
   <option value="region">Student Region</option>
 </select> 
 </label>
 <button ng-click="setfilter()">search</button>
```

javascript:

```
$scope.setfilter = function() {
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.search[ $scope.key ] = $scope.filter;
  console.log( $scope.search );
};
```

Comment: thanks shudham, but i need to add search box inside the dropdown list